# Own model accuracy measure for regression analysis

Tags: regression, python, prediction, mape

Is it possible to produce an own model accuracy measure that takes 100% - MAPE?

If MAPE is 5 % for example, the model accuracy would be 95%? Or is that statistically incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple transformation of the MAPE, so it's as "statistically correct" as using the MAPE in the first place.

Note that the MAPE may exceed 100%, so your accuracy may become *negative*. This can be disconcerting, and lead to strange behavior by forecast consumers, like truncating accuracy at 0%, [which is not a good idea](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/248317/1352).

You may find this thread helpful: [What are the shortcomings of the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352)

Comment: ok great! Thanks for the link.