# How can accuracy be greater than my precision, recall and F-Score metrics?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, model-evaluation, precision-recall, confusion-matrix

I have trained two models to detect gestures using ambient light and solar panels. I am now testing the two models in different light scenarios. I have a Convolutional Neural Network model that performs slightly better than a Random Forest in terms of accuracy, but in darker intensities (<650 lux), RF outperforms CNN in terms of precision and recall.

My question is - How can my CNN model have a greater accuracy than precision, recall and F-score? Such as my living room dataset (350 lux).

And, how can my RF model after 650 lux outperform CNN in precision, recall and F-score but still receive a lower accuracy score than my CNN.

Could someone please help explain this to me,
Thank you in advance

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, f1_score, accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

array_predicted = torch.tensor([])
array_labels =  torch.tensor([])

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()


val_loss = 0
precision, recall, f1, accuracy = [], [], [], []
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    for i,(data, label) in enumerate(test_loader):
        outputs = model(data.to(device))
        val_loss += loss_fn(outputs, label.to(device))

        predicted_classes = torch.max(outputs, 1)[1] # get class from network's prediction

        array_predicted = torch.cat((array_predicted.cpu(),predicted_classes.cpu()),0) 
        array_labels = torch.cat((array_labels.cpu(), label.cpu()),0)

        # calculate P/R/F1/A metrics for batch
        for acc, metric in zip((precision, recall, f1), 
                                (precision_score, recall_score, f1_score)):
            acc.append(
                metric(label.cpu(), predicted_classes.cpu(), average="macro")
            )
        accuracy.append(accuracy_score(label.cpu(), predicted_classes.cpu()))

[sum(x*100)//len(x) for x in [precision, recall, f1, accuracy]]
```

[image: Results Table]
[image: CNN Confusion Matrix]
[image: RF Confusion Matrix]

Comment: Why are you F-scores smaller than precision and recall? It should be in between them since this is a harmonic mean.

Comment: I have added my code above - I have used macro averaging, this may the reason why? A macro-average will compute the metric independently for each class and then take the average (hence treating all classes equally). Would this be the correct way for doing this

Comment: I guess macro averaging may relax that relation.

Answer (score 4):

We can quite quickly look at all possible combinations where $1\leq TP, FP, TN, FN\leq 10$ (there are only $10^4=10,000$ combinations) and easily see that there are many combinations where the accuracy is higher than precision, recall and F1 score. In R:

```
TP <- FP <- TN <- FN <- 1:10

combos <- expand.grid(TP,FP,TN,FN)
names(combos) <- c("TP","FP","TN","FN")
combos$precision <- with(combos,TP/(TP+FP))
combos$recall <- with(combos,TP/(TP+FN))
combos$F1 <- with(combos,2*TP/(2*TP+FP+FN))
combos$accuracy <- with(combos,(TP+TN)/(TP+TN+FP+FN))

head(subset(combos,accuracy>apply(combos[,c("precision","recall","F1")],1,max)))
```

Here is the output, which only shows the first six combinations that satisfy your criterion:

```
    TP FP TN FN precision    recall        F1  accuracy
101  1  1  2  1 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.6000000
201  1  1  3  1 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.6666667
202  2  1  3  1 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.7142857
211  1  2  3  1 0.3333333 0.5000000 0.4000000 0.5714286
301  1  1  4  1 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.7142857
302  2  1  4  1 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.7500000
```

It turns out that out of our $10,000$ possible combinations, no less than $2,386$ satisfy the criterion:

```
> sum(combos$accuracy>apply(combos[,c("precision","recall","F1")],1,max))
[1] 2386
```

This shows that *there is no general relationship* between precision, recall, F1 and accuracy (beyond F1 being defined as the harmonic mean of precision and recall).

---

Note that all these measures suffer from similar weaknesses. All the criticisms against accuracy at these threads apply equally to the other KPIs:

- [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)
- [Is accuracy an improper scoring rule in a binary classification setting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/359909/1352)
- [Classification probability threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352)

Instead, it is better to use probabilistic classifications, and evaluate these using [proper scoring rules](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info).

Comment: (+1) OP uses macro-averaging, so even if the relationship were true (which is not as you demonstrated), I don't think it'd still be true using macro-averaging. Even the loose relationships between precision/recall and F1 score do not hold.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to comment with a question first, but I can't so I will try to write an answer.

**Is your dataset balanced?**

This question is very important. [Accuracy is very sensitive to dataset imbalance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall#Imbalanced_data). In such cases, balanced accuracy is more appropriate and will give you a better value.

> Consider a sample with 95 negative and 5 positive values. Classifying all values as negative in this case gives 0.95 accuracy score [...] For the previous example (95 negative and 5 positive samples), classifying all as negative gives 0.5 balanced accuracy score (the maximum bACC score is one), which is equivalent to the expected value of a random guess in a balanced data set. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall)

Comment: All datasets contain 150 gesture instances. And the same datasets were used for both CNN and RF testing

Comment: And I assume you have ~30 cases for each of the 5 gestures, right?

Comment: [Accuracy, precision, recall and F1 are problematic even for balanced data.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/1352) See also [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/368979/1352).

Comment: That is correct (30 instances x 5 gestures = 150 total gestures)

Comment: I see, Quine. Thanks for the clarifications. I'd go with @StephanKolassa's answer.

Comment: Should I be using micro and macro averaging in this project to calculate my metrics? I would like to calculate the performance as a whole system

Comment: I have added my code above - I have used macro averaging, this may the reason why? A macro-average will compute the metric independently for each class and then take the average (hence treating all classes equally). Would this be the correct way for doing this?