# If the distribution of my target variables is fat-tailed should I use MAE or RMSE?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks

If the distribution of my target variables is fat-tailed should I use MAE or RMSE for the loss function?

Comment: [Why use a certain measure of forecast error (e.g. MAD) as opposed to another (e.g. MSE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45875/why-use-a-certain-measure-of-forecast-error-e-g-mad-as-opposed-to-another-e/45876#45876)

Comment: Is it a question about estimation or evaluation? If the former, the similar question does not provide the answer.